# UNIX system call to unset the reference bit of a specific page in page table?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, page-tables

I'm trying to count hits of a specific set of pages, by hacking the reference bits in the page table. Is there any system call or any other way to unset reference bits (in UNIX-like systems)?

A page table is the data structure used by a virtual memory system in a computer operating system to store the mapping between virtual addresses and physical addresses. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table)

In unix-like systems there is a bit associated with each page table entry, called "reference" bit, which indicates if a page was accessed since the bit was unset. 
The linux kernel **unsets** these reference bits periodically and checks a while after that to know what pages have been accessed, in order to detect "hot" pages. But this information is very coarse grain and low-precision since it doesn't say anything about the number of accesses and their time.

I want to count accesses to specific pages during shorter epochs by unsetting reference bits then check if the pages have been accessed after a short time.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is any system call or CPU interrupt which provides means to unset "reference bits". Otherwise, I need to dive deep into kernel to see what goes on down there.

Comment: Please explain (perhaps with some [MCVE]) what *exactly* are the reference bits for you and how do you hack them. AFAIK, there is no syscalls to get them (even if [mincore(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html) is doing something similar). So **edit your question** to improve it a lot (without much more details it is unclear). See [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for a list of system calls

Comment: Please provide more detail about your objective.

Comment: Look also into [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Perhaps you might be interested by `/proc/self/smaps`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 
just added more info about the problem.

Comment: @wallyk just added more info about the problem.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for your answers, but they don't address my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for resetting the page reference bits.  Page management is a very twitchy aspect of kernel tuning and *no one* wants to upset it.  Of course you could modify the kernel to your needs.

Instead, you might look into [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) which is a debugging and profiling tool for running a single program.  Ordinarily it detects subtle memory errors such as detecting use of a dynamic memory block after it has been freed.

If you need page management information for the system as a whole, I think the most expedient solution is hacking the kernel.